# Is there a timeout on RoleEnvironment.Stopping. On Azure Worker Roles?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

We have some long running tasks on our roles and need to be sure to stop them ima controlled way. initially we tried to use On stop method but MSDN says that

**Important** 
Code running in the OnStop method has a limited time to finish when it is called for reasons other than a user-initiated shutdown. After this time elapses, the process is terminated, so you must make sure that code in the OnStop method can run quickly or tolerates not running to completion. The OnStop method is called after the Stopping event is raised.

And timeout seems to be around 30 seconds and overall shutdown procedure should take no more than 5 minutes.

Does this limitation occurs also on Stopping event? I can't find a clear and direct answer anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Hi ! Did you find something ? the same thing is happening to me, 30 seconds and then shutdown happens